# What is the best CI server for Ruby on Rails Web Applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, hudson

I want to use a CI (Continuous Integration) Server for my Ruby on Rails Application.

If the application were in Java, I should use Hudson CI Server.

What is the best solution in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Might I suggest https://circleci.com?

Comment: Doesn't anyone else think that this is not a question fit for stackoverflow? It's not a Q&A and there is no real answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/ - really simple and yet pretty powerful (especially because of its extensibility) CI server written in ruby with a target on ruby-based projects. Configs are ruby based, really well documented.

Comment: Every project I know that started on CC.rb moved to Hudson/Jenkins eventually. Save yourself the hassle.

Answer (score 5):

Check out TeamCity

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html)

Here is a blog post about it from the Developers:

[TeamCity - Ruby on Rails](http://teamcitydev.blogspot.com/2008/11/most-advanced-continuous-integration.html)

Answer (score 3):

Hudson is not specific to Java builds - it is very good at handling multiple platforms and can launch arbitrary scripts for you.  I recommend it.  There are two ruby plugins already - [Ruby metrics plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Ruby+metrics+plugin) and [Ruby plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Ruby+Plugin)   The latter lets you use Ruby code as a build script.

Answer (score 3):

I make a [hosted Continuous Integration](https://circleci.com) service with deep support for Rails. Check out https://circleci.com. Circle is incredibly fast, takes only one click to set up, and parallelizes your tests automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I personally recommend [CI-Joe](http://github.com/defunkt/cijoe). It's dead simple and it does its job well.

Answer (score 2):

[Tddium](http://www.tddium.com) is much better than these but it launched since the question came out.

Answer (score 1):

[Semaphore](https://semaphoreapp.com) is a hosted CI app that focuses on Ruby and requires no setup. It works with projects that are hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one called Construct: http://github.com/radar/construct

There's also another one called Integrity: http://github.com/integrity/integrity

Both of which we have used for internal projects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the best but also check these out:

[CI Joe](https://github.com/defunkt/cijoe)

[BigTuna](http://bigtuna.appelier.com/)